# How did this notable figure end up in the Old West?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, legends-of-tomorrow

At the end of the Magnificent Eight (ep 11) in Legends of Tomorrow, it turns out the boy who had tuberculosis is H.G. Wells. But Wells was born and raised in Kent, UK. Was this simply the writers being cheesy, or is it one of the differences of the DC universe to ours?

Comment: Maybe he built a Time Machine?

Comment: I don't see any problem here. The mother said the boy wanted to see the west before he died. I didn't get any impression that they had any intention of moving there permanently.

Answer (score 6):

This is a change introduced by the *Legends of Tomorrow* writers. To my knowledge, H.G. Wells never appeared in the American West in any other version of the DC universe.

Within the context of the show, Wells was brought to Dakota by his mother partly to satisfy the boy's "bucket list" dream of seeing the American West, partly on the advice of his doctor:

> **Sarah:** He's been like this on and off for about a year now. He always wanted to see the American West. Our doctor thought a constitutional might do him some good.
>
> <sup>*Legends of Tomorrow* Season 1 Episode 11: "The Magnificent Eight"</sup>

This is obviously impossible to reconcile with our real world, for a couple of reasons:

- Although Wells did visit America, his first visit was in 1906, not 1871; he wrote [a book about the experience](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Future_in_America:_A_Search_After_Realities)
- As well, Wells was born in 1866, meaning he would have been five years old when the events of "The Magnificent Eight" ocurred. The child we meet in the episode is *not* five years old

To my knowledge there is no indication of *why* the writers of the show decided to include Wells as a character.

With the lack of other evidence, I'm forced to conclude that this is just one of the ways the Arrowverse differs from our own universe.

Comment: What about the possibility that some time-travel shenanigans changed Well's age (he was born earlier) and made him travel to the US?

Answer (score 1):

I think it was simply a way to "cover" the events that just occurred. The futuristic events that happened in front of the town folk would be explained away by H. G. Wells stories. Artistic license.

Comment: Even Startrek was more precise with such time  loops. They give Mark Twain a little too old look (in reality he wasn't yet grey)?  Time arrow episode precisely had put two notable figures, him and Jack London, present in right town and right time.